# i had an interview and they ask me and i didn't know the answer i get a answer

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

The question is write a pseudo code that returns true if a given one way linked list reads the same in both directions and false otherwise. In addition we know the size of the list stored in a variable `n`. The expected solution should have computational complexity O(n) and memory complexity O(1).

example : 1->2->3->3->2->1  return true

example : 1->2->3->1->2->3  return false

Comment: The question is whether you are allowed to modify the list. If the list cannot be modified, even temporarily, it's a whole different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reverse a one way linked list, doing a single pass(see the end of this answer). The restriction on the additional memory is quite constraining in this task, so the best approach I figured is a bit hacky.

1. Iterate over the list and reverse the part that comes after its center(namely after position `n/2`) using the algorithm I mentioned above. Save a pointer to the last element in the list - you'll need it for step 2.
2. Simultaneously iterate over the list from the beginning to position `n/2` and the reversed portion(from n to `n/2`). The elements that you iterate over in both portions should match. For this you need two variables - one iterating over the first portion and one for the second(and one to remember how many elements you've already processed).
3. Reverse back the second half of the list so that the list is not changed at the end.

Overall I meet the requirements of the task.

The algorithm to reverse a one-way linked list goes like this(using c++ as example):

```
struct node {
  node* next;
  int data;
};

// reverses a one-way list and returns pointer to the new list head
node* reverse(node* c) {
  node* prev = NULL;
  node* cur = c;
  // I assume the list is NULL terminated;
  while (cur) {
    node* temp = cur->next;
    cur->next = prev;
    prev = cur;
    cur = temp;
  }
  return prev;
}
```

Comment: (Why not reverse the first part?)